# Overlaying an arrow to always point to my direction in Android MapView

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview

What steps do I need to take to draw an arrow on top of my mapview so that it will rotate in a manner so that it is always pointing towards my destination?

Comment: What steps have you tried? What steps do you think you need to take?

Comment: I imagine some kind of custom overlay, but where can I look for rotating a graphic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to update images according to the positions of the destination Do follow this post for reference

'[android drawing path as overlay on mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036139/android-drawing-path-as-overlay-on-mapview)' (for Custom Overlays)

& after that call  [invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) from an UI thread or [postInvalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29) from a non-UI thread on the MapView object you are using , to add items to your maps overlay  .

This way(by invalidating the view & then draw()ing it again) you may position the arrow images to be updated with your destination